# Import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; not possible in latest apache poi.Instead import org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils; is coming

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, fileutils, webpage-screenshot

In the latest Apache poi download(poi-3.15-beta2), while taking screenshot, I need to use FileUtils.copyFile. In its previous version, the imported package was `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`. In the latest download, this package is not coming, and it is giving error in my existing executable code. Now I tried to remove the previous import and it gave import `org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils`;

Code:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(
    scrFile,
    new File(location+"LR_"+strDate+"_scr1.png")
);
```

Gives the error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   `copyFile(File, File)` from the type `FileUtils`

Comment: I think the method is not static. Try creating an instance and call the method with the instance you created.

Comment: No, it's static, it seems to have gone from the project due to some other dependency

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI never bundled or required Apache Commons IO, which contains the FileUtils class and so it seems some other project dragged in this code previously, but does not any longer. See http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components for the list of third-party projects that Apache POI uses.

You should simply add a recent commons-io dependency to your project depending on which type of buildsystem you use, e.g. a normal dependency in Gradle/Maven or the actual jar-file if you have a buildsystem without full dependency-support.

Comment: Thanks @centic. Selenium 3.9.0 update does not provide jars for Apache Commons IO. The below dependency added in pom.xml resolved the issue for me. <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
FileUtils.getFileUtils().copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory + filename));
```

And import file should be:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils;
```